# Multiple definition error of .dll file when compile - Qt and openCV

Tags: qt, opencv, dll

I am trying to setup Qt and openCV following [*qt.io on* How to setup Qt and openCV on Windows](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows).
Everything looks fine, but when I proceed to compile the sample files according to the instructions, I get some problems like that: [multiply defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJpaT.png)

I attempted to solve these by changing the path which I think may be suitable such as the note code under the path (image), but it might not more improve.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you add the following to your post: your full `pro` file, your header and source files, the full errors text, the kit you're using. Avoid posting them as images, include them as text and format them as code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.